# How to fix disk not showing up

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

If I go to Device Manager, i see a hdd connected via usb as Generic HDD USB Device but when i look at the folders, i dont see it showing up.

How do I make it show up so I can access the files in the HDD?

thank you

I am using [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07F7WDZGT/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F7WDZGT)

and my HDD is https://servers4less.com/st1000dm003-seagate-barracuda-1tb-7200rpm-sata-6gbps-64mb-cache-3-5-inch-internal-hard-drive/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwpPKiBhDvARIsACn-gzBX96F2ct6rQ5BNe2elYSPbJdzXXYM0EAsHAhEb5xTw4uG9PGoAFQYaAl36EALw_wcB

EDIT 5/11:
bought [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00LS5NFQ2/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LS5NFQ2) to try

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: It it formatted? Has it been assigned a drive letter?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for the comment. I have done nothing except just plugged it in. How do I check/do both? TIA

Comment: How does it show in Disk Management? Do you, at the very least, know which file system it has? Where was it used before? Please [edit] the question to add useful information.

Comment: @ChanganAuto added a SS for disk management. it says No Media for Disk 1. This was from my old computer's HDD (i.e. having OS and such). I'd imagine the same as current computer's C:/ as it was used for the same purpose, NTFS

Comment: There's either a problem with the adapter you're using or the drive itself is faulty.

Comment: ive used a few different adapters so maybe the drive itself. is there a way to confirm that it is indeed faulty and there is no hope in recovering it? anything I can try? Would love to recover family photos

Comment: Yes, you can connect the drive directly to (supposedly) SATA controller instead of the external adapters, as always. If it can't be shown and/or formated then it¡s busted. If however it works then the problem is with the adapters. The former is way more likely, of course.

Comment: Honestly, if data is important you should have backups and with so much cloud file services available and cheap external media there's really no excuse.

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes i do that now (I use google photos). this computer is from 6 or so years ago

Comment: And now I see the problem. The adapter you just edited into the question is ONLY for 2.5" drives. 3.5" drives need external power supply that can't be added to that sort of USB adapters. There are enclosures for that purpose with their own power supply.

Comment: You need this https://www.amazon.com/s?k=usb+enclosure+3.5&crid=1I4LXR1IPEBJ&sprefix=usb+enclosure+%2Caps%2C182&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_2_14

Comment: ah okay let me give that a try and will update the post

Comment: Yes, that one should work, provided the drive is OK.

Comment: @ChanganAuto looks like more errors. i presume this means hdd is a goner? I m not able to initialize the disk

Comment: Are you using the proper adapter now? If so then definitely the HDD has problems. If you want to have any chance of recovering data from it you neither attempt to initialize nor format regardless of what Windows suggests. You can try some recovery software preferably working in a an image of that drive made with another software to somewhere else "as is" instead of working directly on the drive.

Comment: Yes, im using the one with enclosures. it's not letting me initialize the disk for some reason

Comment: That's bad news but, again, you shouldn't even try to do that if you want to have any chance of data recovery.

Comment: Does it spin up even?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen yes It's spinning

Answer (score 2):

**Elimination**

In general, if a storage device is not detected you play the game of 'elimination'. So you replace components one by one to see if you can determine the bad one (cables, enclosures). If you're dealing with a spinning drive use your ears: Even the most silent drives should produce some noise/sounds.

**Get the right enclosure/adapter**

Make sure, that if you're using an enclosure or SATA > USB adapter that it can actually power the drive. As a rule of thumb for 3.5" drives you need an external power-source, USB alone is not enough.

**No spin and your using the right, non faulty components?**

Then probably some component on the PCB failed. Some can fix yourself by removing them so you can recover the data. By snipping the TVS diode you can often get the drive to spin again.

[image]

Note I am not a HDD expert but here it goes:

If TVS is the issue with multimeter in continuity mode, place black probe at the side where lines ||| are, red other side you get a beep. So beep is bad.

In diode mode black probe at ||| and red other side, if reading is close to zero the TVS diode is bad.

In which case I'd remove it, hook up drive. If it spins save data. Note that by removing the diode you removed protection as well so it's *not meant to be a permanent solution*!

If fuse is shorted, remove and bridge it (solder blob, but .1 copper wire is nicer) *for temporary solution*.

If you prefer watching someone diagnose, this is a nice video: https://youtu.be/2YZ0LBhFCZY

**Incorrect or no detection**

For data from a drive to be recoverable, it needs to be correctly detected. So as long as Windows Disk Management does not detect the drive with the correct capacity you can not recover data from it.

[image]

If you get a different capacity than the expected one, in general you're dealing with a 'firmware issue'. And in general, to recover the data you'd need to send the drive to a lab. Some times the firmware issue is a direct result of surface damage, so best to not power on the drive at all in this case, specially as there's isn't much to gain by powering it up anyway.